# Mongo - compact collection in background

Tags: mongodb

I want to compact very large collection in mongo (around 800GB of data).
I know that I need to run it on separate replicas (first secondaries, then promote another node to primary, and then compact last secondary). And that is fine.
to do this i need to run:

`db.runCommand({compact: "collectionName"})`

But i want to execute it in background. And this is my problem because when I execute:

`mongosh mongodb://database.host.net:27017/databaseName --eval "db.runCommand({compact: "collectionName"})"`

I'm getting message:

`ReferenceError: collectionName is not defined`

How can i run compacting in background ?

Answer (score 1):

The message `ReferenceError: collectionName is not defined` you're getting is due to how your command is formatted. You need to use different quotes for embedded quotes, otherwise it will cause syntax errors like yours.

Try instead of:

```bash
mongosh mongodb://database.host.net:27017/databaseName --eval "db.runCommand({compact: "collectionName"})"
```

A command:

```bash
mongosh mongodb://database.host.net:27017/databaseName --eval 'db.runCommand({compact: "collectionName"})'
```

Note how I used single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` around `--eval`.

And to run it on background, use this:

```bash
nohup mongosh mongodb://database.host.net:27017/databaseName --eval 'db.runCommand({compact: "collectionName"})' &
```

`&` makes a command run on background. And `nohup` makes a command run even when terminal is closed.